# ASP.NET Core Passing Entity with Linked Data to View and Back

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm passing an object with a N:M relationship to a view:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    ...    
    public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, I eager load the collection and pass the object to the view:

```
public IActionResult Modify(int? id)
{
    var obj = _db.Projects.Where(i => i.ProjectId == id).Include(c => c.CrewMembers).First();
    return View(obj);
}
```

The view looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input asp-for="ProjectId" hidden />
        <input asp-for="CrewMembers" hidden />
        ...
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The data seems to "arrive" on the view just fine (if I look at the Model object, it contains the CrewMembers collection), however when I submit the form, the "Projects" collection returns empty:

```
//POST
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Modify(Project obj)
{
    //obj.CrewMembers IS NOW EMPTY(!)

    _db.Projects.Update(obj);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

So how can I preserve the Collection when passing it to/from the view? It seems the `<input asp-for="CrewMembers" hidden />` trick doesn't work...

Comment: I think you should serialize the CrewMembers collection before sending it to the view. And deserialize when receiving from the front to the back. Perhaps it will be enough to serialize only IDs.

Comment: @RemoPini: **Actually this very bad idea to pass entity as the model to a view**. Read for example this article: [Why it's not a good idea to pass entities as Models in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2330535/6630084)

Comment: @Victor: I not sure I understand 100% what you're getting at, most examples / tutorials for asp.net core seem to suggest that passing an object to a view is absolutely fine. That is how it is supposed to work. Otherwise, how am I supposed to update the object with all the changes done on the webform? Field by field from the form data on the controller seems extremely clunky.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Hm.. i could do that, but I need the data on the view, so I have to deserialize it on the view again, which makes it a bit pointless (serialize on controller and deserialize on view is the same as just passing the object directly). It's the way BACK that's the issue. I'm hoping there's a "built in" way of getting the complete object back instead of having to deal with a part of the object in a different way (serializing/deserializing). Further down the road, I will have to modify that part of the data on the view, so it might get a bit complicated if that's the only way.

Comment: You have no CrewMembers data on the view. `<input asp-for="CrewMembers" hidden />` - open source code in the browser - what do you see?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58627155/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Thx! That was very helpful. I'll look into how to incorporate it into my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Modify([Bind("ProjectId,CrewMembers")]Project obj)
{
    //obj.CrewMembers IS NOW EMPTY(!)

    _db.Projects.Update(obj);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And in the view , use one input for each element of the list.

```
@for(int i=0;i<Model.CrewMembers.Count();i++)
{
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CrewMembers[i].xxxx"/>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CrewMembers[i].xxxx"/>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CrewMembers[i].xxxx"/>
...
}
```

Comment: While that probably works, it will generate a LOT of data on the page (think 60 items with around 20 fields each, so 120 hidden inputs). I think I prefer the serialize/deserialize option posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58627155/5045688